# Selector default value arrives later then value set in action

Tags: angular, observable, state-management, ngxs

I have a state with a default value. I have a component which have a selector and a subscribe block in its ngOnInit. Strangely, the data coming from the backend is overwritten in this subscribe block, because the init data arrives later then the real data I need...
Console log statements in order:

```
ngOnInit
initData (with state default value)
pre PatchState searchInit (data came from the server)
initData (data came from the server)
initData (with state default value)
```

I tried the subscribe with pipe(first()), also tried it in setTimeout block, no idea what is happening...

Code:

state:

```
@State<XStateModel>({
  name: 'x',
  defaults: {
    searchInitData: {
      types: [ { id: 1, imageUrl: '', name: 'd'} ],
    }
  }
})

@Action(FetchXSearchInitData)
getSearchInitData({ getState, patchState }: StateContext<XStateModel>) {       
  this.xService.getXSearchInitData().subscribe(initData => {
    console.log('pre PatchState searchInit', initData);
    patchState({
      searchInitData: initData
    });
  });
}
```

component:

```
@Select(XState.searchInitData)
searchInitData$: Observable<XSearchInitData>;

ngOnInit() {
  console.log('ngOnInit');
  this.store.dispatch(new FetchXSearchInitData());
  this.searchInitData$.subscribe((result: XSearchInitData) => {
    if (!result) {
      console.log('NULL init data');
      return;
    }
    console.log('initData', result);
    }
  );
```

Comment: try subscribing to the state before you dispatch the action.

Comment: @RichDuncan Thanks, I liked the idea, but unfortunately the same happens, the default value arrives twice, second one is later than the value I need...

Comment: @AttGal what does your selector look like?